# How to add a line to the bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-navigation

I want to add a line on top of the navigation bar similar to what's in the image here (except this is not a navigation bar).[image: Line]

How should I go about doing this? Do I need to add a lineview?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tab_contents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:text="Home"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:text="Search"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a single view with a height of 1db or 2db and align it to the top of the Bottom View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tab_contents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"></ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_button1"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Home" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nav_button2"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:background="#C5C5C5" />


</RelativeLayout>
```